# Get the list of active users[ users who has connected atleast once in last 6 months] in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

Get the list of active users[ users who has connected atleast once in last 6 months] in Solaris10

Answer (score 1):

Try with "[last](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/man/solaris/last.1.html)".

You just need to parse the output to get what you want.